# Stream processed frame from openCV to IP

Tags: opencv, image-processing, video-streaming, gstreamer

I have developed a program in Visual Studio 10 using OpenCV and C++.
It is processing frames in real-time from a camera.
As output, I get processed IplImages which I show on display as video using `cvShowImage`.
Now I want to stream these frames/video to an IP address so that user can see it using a browser(mjpeg) or in VLC (H.264). I did some research and got to know about GStreamer. But it is not available for VS10 and all the links are dead.

Is there any other way to do it without rebuilding my OpenCV library?

Answer (score 1):

GStreamer is available for Visual Studio 2019, and works for opencv 4.2. 
This is easy, but a lot of space for mistakes. The Gstreamer pipe works. The extended description is available here [Tutorial](https://funvision.blogspot.com/2020/03/compile-opencv-4-for-visual-studio-2019.html).

[image: Gstreamer result]

I used3)
- OpenCV source opencv-4.2.0
- OpenCV source opencv_contrib-4.2.0
- Cmake 3.17 release candidate 3, This is important. 
I used development and runtime installer for MSVC GStreamer
Gstreamer 1.16.2 runtime installer
Gstreamer 1.16.2 development installer
[image: what to download]
The following steps are common for OpenCV to build from source and OpenCV installation. Additionally, these resources needs to be added during cmake configuration.
[image: Gstreamer Cmake opencv config]

Now build OpenCV project generated by CMAKE in Visual Studio 2019. The last important thing is to set environmental variables to find GStreamer Runtime. Into system variable path: add

- xxx\1.0\x86_64\bin
- xxx\1.0\x86_64\lib
- xxx\1.0\x86_64\lib\gstreamer-1.0
  [image: Environmental variables]

You need to use VideoWriter with gstreamer Pipeline.

```
VideoWriter writer( "appsrc ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=320,height=240 ! theoraenc ! oggmux ! tcpserversink host=192.168.0.116 port=8080 recover-policy=keyframe sync-method=latest-keyframe unit-format=buffers units-max=1 buffers-max=0 sync=true ",
        0,
        5,
        Size(320, 240),
        true);
```

Comment: tcpserversink doesn't work in Chrome, and in firefox it is stuck to black screen. I was hoping a way to send mjpeg images. I have created the code, but it is only displaying on my computer on http://127.0.0.1:xxxx  I want to stream it to all connected devices. Do you have any knowledge about that?